Jacobian and chain rule contradiction, Geodesic equation
Consider two components of a contravariant vector related by the jacobian $J^\bar{\mu}_\mu = \frac{\partial x^{\bar{\mu}}}{\partial x^\mu}$ , $x^{\bar{\mu}}= x^{\bar{\mu}}(x^\mu)$
$x^\bar{\mu} = J^\bar{\mu}_\mu x^\mu$
Taking the derivative of this expression with respect to proper time using the product rule
$$\dot{x}^\bar{\mu} = J^\bar{\mu}_\mu \dot{x}^\mu + \dot{J}^\bar{\mu}_\mu x^\mu$$
Now consider the same expression using the chain rule
$$\frac{\partial x^{\bar{\mu}}}{\partial\tau} = \frac{\partial x^{\bar{\mu}}}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \tau} =J^\bar{\mu}_\mu \dot{x}^\mu $$
These expressions are different, why does the chain rule fail in this case? What am i missing. This is in relation to my textbook derivation of the geodesic equation  where they employ the chain rule when evaluating the inside proper time derivative here:


I think there's a contradiction in your first sentence, the coordinates themselves in both systems are related by the coordinate transformation, it is only tensors that transform with the Jacobian of the transformation

Yeah I realised that a second ago! Re wording my question in this manner ie the components of the contravariant vectors are related by the jacobian,  does my problem still exist?

Yes, it is not a semantic issue. The Jacobian of the transformation can't generally be the coordinate transformation itself! And since $x^\mu$ are the coordinates in what they write, it can't form a tensor/vector.

First of all, note that in general the Jacobian of the coordinate transformation is not identical with the coordinate transformation itself. As you mention in your first sentence, you first need to define the transformation, relating in this case the unbarred coordinates to the barred ones:
$$ x^{\bar\mu} = x^{\bar\mu}(x^\mu), \tag{1}$$
to even be able to compute its Jacobian. i.e. only given a set of functions such as $(1)$, are we even able to define:
$$ J^{\bar\mu}{}_{\mu} = \frac{\partial x^{\bar\mu}}{\partial x^\mu}\ . $$
So the following part you've written:

$x^\bar{\mu} = J^\bar{\mu}_\mu x^\mu$
Taking the derivative of this expression with respect to proper time using the product rule
$$\dot{x}^\bar{\mu} = J^\bar{\mu}_\mu \dot{x}^\mu + \dot{J}^\bar{\mu}_\mu x^\mu$$

Starts from an incorrect relation between the coordinates, thus leading you to a result which is incorrect.
The part right after that however:

$$\frac{\partial x^{\bar{\mu}}}{\partial\tau} = \frac{\partial x^{\bar{\mu}}}{\partial x^\mu}\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \tau} =J^\bar{\mu}_\mu \dot{x}^\mu $$

Is correct, and is just how the four velocity vectors $\large\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \tau}$ and $\large\frac{\partial x^{\bar{\mu}}}{\partial\tau}$ in the two coordinate systems are related. Being contravariant vectors, their components transform as written, via the Jacobian.
Now about the derivation in the screenshot, I think the one thing you need to take note of is that the quantity that transforms like a tensor in this derivation is not $\ddot{\xi}^{\alpha}$, but rather the covariant equivalent of it, which we sometimes write as1:
$$ \frac{D{\dot{\xi}^{\alpha}}}{D\tau}, $$
Now since in the LIF this quantity is zero, it also transforms to zero, as contraction with the Jacobian takes a zero vector to a zero vector.
But, the reason they get a non-tensorial term when they rewrite $\ddot{\xi}^{\alpha}$ in terms of the general coordinates $x^\alpha$, is due to applying the transformation to the four velocity being derived, rather than to the entire tensor which is the covariant derivative of $\dot{\xi}^\alpha$. They do that because they want to find an explicit expression for the covariant derivative in the general coordinates, which turns out to just be the geoedesic equation.
In the LIF, we don't "see" the geodesic equation fully because covariant differentiation happens to be identical with partial differentiation, due to the $\Gamma$'s all vanishing:
$$\frac{D{\dot{\xi}^{\alpha}}}{D\tau} = \frac{\partial{\dot{\xi}^{\alpha}}}{\partial\tau}, \tag{2}$$
So what this derivation shows is in fact that:
$$ \frac{D{\dot{\xi}^{\alpha}}}{D\tau} = \frac{D{\dot{x}^{\alpha}}}{D\tau} = 0 $$
and it is just that $(2)$ doesn't hold in the general coordinates, $x^\alpha$. Writing out the explicit expression for $\large\frac{D{\dot{x}^{\alpha}}}{D\tau}$, in terms of partial derivatives, yields another term which is just the derived quantity multiplied by the Christoffel symbols, which don't vanish in the general coordinates, as explained.

Thank you, I have had some lacks in my understanding about the definition of contravariant vectors. Just to be clear,  a contravariant vector is one such that in 2 frames we can say $v^\bar{\mu} = \frac{dx^\bar{\mu}}{d\lambda} $, $v^\mu = \frac{dx^\mu}{d\lambda}$ for which lambda is some frame independant parameter? For which using the chain rule, we obtain the standard transformation between contravariant vectors. Taking the derivative of the this again with respect to the same parameter, due tocthe product rule can not transform as a tensor (ie 4 acceleration) unless we -

Invoke the covariant derivative.

That is only a very specific example of a contravariant vector, because again we usually write $x^{\mu}$ and $x^{\bar{\mu}}$ to represent the coordinates in both frames. Now, what you've written implies, we assume we have the world line of a particle for example, parameterized by an affine parameter $\lambda$: $$ x^{\mu} = x^{\mu}(\lambda),$$ which is not a tensor/vector in itself. It is true however, is that one of the most basic tensors we form in SR/GR in this context is then: $$ v^{\mu} = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^\mu}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}, $$ and this the four velocity. For massive particles...

we can also put $\lambda=\tau$, which provides a natural parameterization. But now, in order to take higher derivatives in $\lambda$ which will form a tensor, we must use the covariant derivative. This is because, as the derivation shows, in general coordinates we must account for the change of the basis vectors, that's accounted for by the Christoffel symbols, which we get from how the covariant derivative is defined. See for example this

Also see relevant questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129219/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/640419/ , especially the answer to the second one, for a more rigorous approach/explanation, that may help you make sense of these matters.
